# Not able to send mail using jailkit user in RHEL7

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, postfix-mta, rhel7, rhel5

OS:Rhel-7

I am using version jailkit-2.19. While configuring mail in jail user I faced following issues:

1) when I hit mail command "echo "text" | mail -s "subject" xyz@gmail.com"
I encountered "/usr/sbin/sendmail: No such file or directory" error.

2) to resolve this error I copied sendmail file with dependencies using jk_cp -j command.

3) I again got different error message after entering mail command "send-mail: fatal: file /etc/postfix/main.cf: parameter default_privs: unknown user name value: nobody"

4) to overcome this issue I added nobody,postfix user into passwd file

5) and added postdrop into /etc/groups file

6) After clearing above issues i got new error message "send-mail: fatal: chdir /var/spool/postfix: No such file or directory"

7) To overcome above issue I copied /var/spool/postfix user into jail user

8) after updating above files i face another error message "send-mail: fatal: execvp /usr/sbin/postdrop: No such file or directory"

9) to overcome above issue I updated postdrop into new user

10) After this again I got error "error while loading shared libraries: libmysqlclient.so.18:".

After clearing all errors mail command is working fine with exit status "0", But I am not receiving any kind of mail, neither getting any mail logs on server.